# I am getting s3 error: An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-iam, policy

`enter code here`getting:  An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied

But I have a IAM policy set and using aws CLI with --profile that has the policy attached.  IAM policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-repository"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-repository/data/*"
        }
    ]
}

aws --profile my-repository s3 ls

An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListBuckets operation: Access Denied
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the following IAM permission to do `aws s3 ls`:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: so, I can't restrict the ListBucket to just one resource (bucket)?

Comment: I see what you mean.... I made the change and kept the listBucket restriction.... that worked!! thanks.

Comment: my policy is now:

Comment: {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-repository"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-repository/data/*"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: sorry.... I did not enter the entire policy..... posting answer now

Comment: How do you actually use this role once you assign it to a user.  I add it as an inline policy to an IAM user and I still get permission denied.  I understand creating and assigning the policy, but after that do I need to do something to my aws config/credentials files?

Comment: @BrianWiley If you added this permission to the user/role that your cli is using, then you don't need to change anything in your AWS CLI, just run `aws s3 ls` and it will work. If you added this permission to a different role/user, then you need to re-config the CLI in order to use the permission.

Comment: @jellycsc yes this was actually just a symptom of the issue.  The real issue was that AWS added `AWSCompromisedKeyQuarantineV2` policy to the user which prevents listing all buckets :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I was [using attribute-based access control (ABAC)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/introduction_attribute-based-access-control.html) and I had accidentally set a condition that in order for a user to be able to do the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` action, the resource must contain a specific tag.

```
{
  "Sid": "AllowInteractOnlyWithOwnTaggedResources",
  "Effect": "Deny",
  "Action": [
    "s3:ListAllMyBuckets"
  ],
  "Resource": "*",
  "Condition": {
    "StringNotEquals": {
      "aws:ResourceTag/access": "${aws:PrincipalTag/access}"
    }
  }
}
```

The resource tag condition doesn't work for the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` action, and so AWS gave me an AccessDenied error.

The reason I was stumped by this is that the above policy was a [service control policy (SCP)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/organizations/latest/userguide/orgs_manage_policies_scps.html), and yet I got a plain "AccessDenied" error when the action didn't work. Usually, when an action is denied by the SCP, you get an "AccessDenied with an explicit deny in a service control policy" error.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-repository"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:GetObjectAcl",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:GetObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::my-repository/data/*"
        }
    ]
}
```